# How can I add an attribute to a database query before returning?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

So I have something like this:

```
$comments = Comments::select('id', 'topic', 'parent_id', 'username', 'comment', 'upvotes', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
        ->where('topic', '=', $topic)
        ->get();

// I'd like to add a human readable datetime difference like
// 1 day ago, 2 days ago, etc. before I return the $comments variable here.

return json_encode($comments);
```

For a single row I would do something like this:

```
$comment->created_at->diffForHumans();
```

How can I add an extra attribute to all the rows, something like carbon_date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the `$comments` array and add the attribute to each element.

```
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    $comment->carbon_date = $comment->created_at->diffForHumans();
}
```

Comment: That would provide the dates but how would I update the $comments variable with the additional attribute?

Comment: It modifies the object in place, doesn't it? You said that's how to do it for a single row.

Comment: If not, assign to a property.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you. I'll choose yours as the answer in 4 minutes.

Comment: PHP is so simple sometimes, it's counter intuitive.